# ESPP and payroll tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, espp

"I participate in my company's stock purchase plan ESPP at a 10% discount. purchases are made quarterly.  My company has been adding the 10% discounted amount onto my payroll quarterly and taxing it. I have not sold any shares. Is that correct?"

Comment: please specify your country.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're being taxed at purchase, it sounds like this is a non-qualified ESPP. Under those rules, the 10% discount is taxed like regular income (including Social Security and Medicare taxes). More details under the 'Tax Calculation' section on [this page](https://communications.fidelity.com/sps/fidelityinvestor/2014/Q1/espp/article.html). There will be tax consequences again when you sell, either a capital gain or loss with the cost basis being the fair market value at purchase (i.e. the price before the discount).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I appreciate you taking the time